# node debugging in vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm not especially familiar with server-side debugging. I'm running node on the back end of a react app. I had the debugger working but I started mucking with some other settings and messed it up. I tried to use VSCode's out of the box debugger settings but I keep getting an error. this is what it told me to put in my launch.json

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach",
  "port": 9229
}
```

and here is the error I keep getting.

```
Debugging with inspector protocol because Node.js version could not be determined 
(Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229)
```

Anybody experience this? I don't want anything special. I just want to be able to hit breakpoints